# how do i connect to rabbitmq using amqpnetlite dll

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

i have tried this code

```
 try
        {
            Address address = new Address("host", 5672, "user", "pass", "/tmdgdai");
            connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();

            Session session = new Session(await connectionFactory.CreateAsync((address)));
            SenderLink senderLink = new SenderLink(session, "sender-link", "q1");
            var message = new Message() { BodySection = new Data() { Binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputMessage.Text) } };
            await senderLink.SendAsync(message);

            senderLink.Send(message);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            logs.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

but get the exception

`System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.`

can anyone help me how to connect to rabbitmq server using qmpnetlite?

Answer (score 0):

The AmqpNetLite client is an AMQP 1.0 based client and does not work against the older non-standard AMQP protocol version that RabbitMQ uses.  There seems to be a [plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0) that might allow you add AMQP 1.0 support to RabbitMQ but you would need to do some testing with AmqpNetLite to ensure everything works as expected.

Comment: If you enable the rabbitmq 1_0 plugin, it does work. See answer above. I tested it, and with some tweaking I got it working with AMQP net lite in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the AMQP 1.0 plugin in RabbitMQ you can do this.

rabbitmq    | 2021-10-10 09:16:31.966360+00:00 [info] <0.699.0> Server startup complete; 5 plugins started.
rabbitmq    | 2021-10-10 09:16:31.966360+00:00 [info] <0.699.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
rabbitmq    | 2021-10-10 09:16:31.966360+00:00 [info] <0.699.0>  * **rabbitmq_amqp1_0**
rabbitmq    | 2021-10-10 09:16:31.966360+00:00 [info] <0.699.0>  * rabbitmq_management
rabbitmq    | 2021-10-10 09:16:31.966360+00:00 [info] <0.699.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
rabbitmq    | 2021-10-10 09:16:31.966360+00:00 [info] <0.699.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent

I used Docker in the Dockerfile like this:

FROM rabbitmq:3-management

RUN echo '[rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_management_visualiser,rabbitmq_amqp1_0].' > enabled_plugins

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_amqp1_0

The C# code:

```
        //Critical: Use this Address ctor,
        //"amqp://localhost:6000" as otherwise you end up with protocol errors...
        var publishAddress = new Address("amqp://localhost:6000");
        _connection = new Connection(publishAddress);
        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.AMQP.ContainerId = "test";
    
        var session = new Session(_connection);

        _sender = new SenderLink(
            session,
            "sender-link",
            "q1");

        var amqpMessage = new Message()
        {
            BodySection = new Data { Binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("boe-utf8") },
            Header = new Header() 
            { 
                Durable = false ,
                
            },
            Properties = new Properties()
            {
                MessageId = "11"

            }
        };
        _sender.Send(amqpMessage);
```

Note: I opened up port 5672 as 6000 in my Docker:

```
 rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    build:
      context: ./Docker
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
   ports:
    - 6000:5672
    - 7000:15692 
    - 8000:15672 
volumes:
 - ./Docker/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq:rw
 - ./Docker/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro
 - ./Docker/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
```

rabbitmq.conf:

```
  management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

definitions.json:

```
{
 "users": [
{
  "name": "guest",
  "password": "guest5000",
  "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
  "tags": "administrator"
}
],
"vhosts":[
    {"name":"/"}
],
"queues":{"name":"q1","vhost":"/","durable":false,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{}}
  ]
}
```